# conflict __glibc==2.17=0 tensorflow=2.4

Tags: python, tensorflow

I install tensorflow using `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=2.4`
and I got

```
Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package __glibc conflicts for:
@/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0
tensorflow=2.4 -> tensorflow-estimator[version='>=2.4.1'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
@|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0
```

May I know how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please verify that you have followed all the steps as mentioned in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) link to install tensorflow in your linux environment? Let us know if the issue still persists.

Comment: Hello TFer2, there is no conflict when I install tensorflow together with while creating a new environment.